# How to replace a string from an entry with another string in a file-Python-Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, replace, overwrite

Im trying i have 2 entries called `oldpassword` and `newpassword`. The user must type the `oldpassword` which already exists in a file in a specific format. If he types a valid `oldpassword` he gets to change his password. The problem lies within the `.replace` function in Python. I cant get it to replace the old password with the new password in the file. The code is this :

```
def checkpw():
    oldpass = oldpasswordvar.get()
    newpass = newpasswordvar.get()
    with open('file.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for line in f:
            list = line.split()
            pw = list[3]
            if pw == oldpass:
             f.write(line.replace(pw,newpass))
```

And the file looks like this :

```
2 3 101 www
4 5 102 qpw
6 7 103 lpl
8 9 104 qpq
```

So basically

- i read the file as individual strings with `split` and
- then i check if `oldpass` is equal with `list[3] = 'www','qpw','lpl','qpq'`
- If its equal i want to replace that string with the `newpass` variable

but all it does is: **just append a whole new line at the end of the file**.
It doesnt replace the string. Any ideas?

Comment: You *cannot* write a modified line into the middle of a file like that - if the new password is longer than the old, there's no room for it!  Even if it was the same length, the file position has already advanced beyond the line that the old password was read from, so `.write()` will overwrite something else.  (Your `.replace()` approach is fundamentally broken, anyway.  Imagine that somebody had set their password to `1`, and then changed it: you'd replace that `1` in the 3rd field as well.)

Comment: So is there any way to go through this?

Comment: **1.** Read the whole file [`.readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines). **2.** Make your changes. **3.** Rewrite the whole file [`.writerlines(lines)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines)

Comment: Problem solved from another thread.Thanks for the help guys!